# How to understand the learning rate choosing in SGD

Tags: gradient, deep-learning

Like most numerical hyper-parameters,
the learning rates should be explored in the log-domain, and there is not much to be gained
by refining it more than a factor of 2, whereas the dynamic range explored could be around
10^6, learning rates are typically below 1.

in this paragraph, I want to know 
1: what is the meaning of log-domain?
2: what is the use of the factor of 2?
3: what is the meaning of  dynamic range?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably talking about how to scale learning rates

1: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale

2: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor

3: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range

Comment: I have read the articles, but I remain to be confused. Could u give me an example?